# US phone number verification in QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt5, qt-creator

I am having a hard time getting a verification system for a US phone numbers working.

*Please note that I am a self studied 'dev' that is just trying some things for curiosity and that my knowledge is very limited*

okay so as mentioned i am trying to validate a US phone number from a LineEdit, the number should be in the following format +1 000-000-0000

so after some searching on google i found a post that helped me setup a verification, but i cannot get it to work for my format,

```
{
    //QRegExp nv("^\\+?(1 |)[0-9]{3}+(-|)[0-9]{3}+(-|)[0-9]{3}+(-|)[0-9]{4}$");
    QRegExp nv("^\\+1(\\d{10})$");
    nv.setPatternSyntax(QRegExp::RegExp);
    bool regMat = nv.exactMatch(num);
    if(regMat == false)
    {
    QMessageBox *message = new QMessageBox(this);
    message->setWindowModality(Qt::NonModal);
    message->setText("Please insert a valid phone number");
    message->setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok);
    message->setWindowTitle("ERROR");
    message->setIcon(QMessageBox::Information);
    message->exec();
    ui->edtCustPhone->setFocus();
    ui->edtCustPhone->selectAll();
    return false;
    }else{
    return true;
    }
};
```

now I'm not sure what language this is (I'm guessing JavaScript)

```
("^\\+?(1 |)[0-9]{3}+(-|)[0-9]{3}+(-|)[0-9]{3}+(-|)[0-9]{4}$")
```

but I cannot seem to get my head around why it is not accepting number in the format that I want, and keeps prompting the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working using a site that someone on discordd suggested:
https://ihateregex.io/expr/phone/#

turns out my REGEX

```
("^\\+?(1 |)[0-9]{3}+(-|)[0-9]{3}+(-|)[0-9]{3}+(-|)[0-9]{4}$")
```

has one to many

```
[0-9]{3}
```

iterations... and these where also stated incorrectly:

```
+(-|)
```

after some testing I got this to to work for me:

```
 QRegExp nv("^\\+?(1 |)[0-9]{3}\\-[0-9]{3}\\-[0-9]{4}$");
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a regular expression. See the QRegExp class documentation.

The original regex looks a lot closer (the one you commented out) than the one you've kept.

Comment: hey, thanks yeah after some struggle i found the mistakes and posted now what i had to fix, but thanks for taking the time to try and help